# GIT: Managing repos between two remote development teams

Tags: git

Apologies if this has been asked before, if it has then its not clearly labelled as such.

I have two development teams in two different countries, each working on the same project but developers are working against local office Git repos. Each office operates in different time zones, about 8hrs apart but we like to keep things up to date on an hourly basis. So devs in OfficeA pull/push to their own repo and OfficeB pull/push to their own. Project code/structure is identical.

OfficeA is the true master and where deployments to CI and UAT take place. So we set things up as follows:

- OfficeB has their repo setup as a cloned mirror of OfficeA's repo:

  > git clone --mirror git@gitlab:project.git
- An hourly task is setup for OfficeB to update their repo with changes from OfficeA via (no one is branching, we all simply work on the master branch:

  > git fetch
  >   git push

Now because of timezones no issues arose for sometime but it seems this solution as noted above is not what we should be doing because we are losing code, often OfficeB has a commit or two missing in the morning and this is fxied via a simple push from each dev's machine since changes are not lost from their local machine repos.

I've looked further and it appears this whoel approach is incorrect and not what we should do in that a mirror is exactly just that. So what is the best solution for maintaining a HQ repo with a remote, each repo being used by local devs and changes from BOTH sides merged together and pushed out so BOTH servers reflect each other? I am guessing OfficeB should have TWO repos, one for devs to use and one a mirror'd clone of HQ. The sync scripts then play with updates and merges between these two repo folders in OfficeB.

Please confirm if this is the way to go and offer your thoughts or scripts or anything that may help. Git seems powerful but oh so confusing and documentation is laden with git lingo its giving it a really bad name across our organisation :-(

I'd expect this to be a VERY common setup for people working in international companies so surprised it hasn't been easier to find clear and concise tips or maybe my 'google'ing' plainly sux :-)

Thanks in advance guys

**PROPOSAL**

OfficeA remains as is... OfficeB create a bare mirror clone of OfficeA... an additional clone is made from the mirror clone and it is this one that DEVs all work with. the original mirror is purely for the sync process acting as intermediary for safe handling of conflicts and once attended to + resolved it pushes to its remote master..

Or should both cloned repos be standard clones with working directories?

Comment: If you update only every hour instead of after every commit, how can you keep the repositories synchronized. IMHO you should synchronize after every change. (And by the way, it is Git, not GIT.)

Comment: sync after every change is a possibility but not that much usage happening at the same time to warrant this..and it is spelt Git in my post just not the subject line.. you know, like email prefixes.. why so grumpy?

Comment: "no one is branching, we all simply work on the master branch" - that is probably the first thing you need to fix... Learning how to use `git` properly will make most other issues much easier to solve.

Comment: i completely understand this actually and was also my concern but its how our HQ office operate (and who also erroneously directed me to the current flawed model)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a simple problem.

When you have two repositories that simultaneously update each one of them you can get conflicts when sync-ing them.

Conflicts may need human interaction to be solved the correct way. One way to solve this is to always sync, while pushing to B, A is locked down and then B is pushing to A and A is unlocked again, and the other way around. This is probably not a good solution for you. I suppose that you have bandwidth limitations, otherwise all devs would work directly with A.

So, let's do some magic. You have a timezone difference. Let's move the master repository twice every day.

Make B read only and let all devs push to A. Let B do a pull. Make A read only and let all devs push to B. Let A do a pull and so on.

You would always have fast-forward updates (if you don't rewrite history, then you need some other way to sync, like rsync). And therefore no merge issues.

And with some smart DNS (or maybe git-hooks) logic you could make this fully transparent to the devs. For example, pushing from B when B is read only will automatic push to A instead, with lower speed of course but it will still work.

Comment: thanks for the replies thus far guys!

the HQ repo is not externally accessible and i want to avoid the local devs needing to get themselves setup with VPN accounts along with updating the OfficeB network to allow the form of encryption and other security settings for the VPN connection to be established .. the OfficeB repo sites on a server at our data centre that is setup with a permanent VPN connection so this model seems sound.

Comment: have updated to better convey my proposed approach for you gurus to yay or nay it... as always, kudos and appreciation all round...